# Nuxt and vuex-persist: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm getting the following error when using `npm up` after installing `npm install --save vuex-persist`, what's wrong with this package and my configuration?

I'm using Nuxt `^2.15.8`.

```
❯ npm up
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: myproject@1.1.1
npm ERR! Found: vue@2.6.14
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   peer vue@"*" from @nuxtjs/auth-next@5.0.0-1643791578.532b3d6
npm ERR!   node_modules/@nuxtjs/auth-next
npm ERR!     @nuxtjs/auth-next@"5.0.0-1643791578.532b3d6" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer vue@"^2.6.4" from vuetify@2.6.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/vuetify
npm ERR!     vuetify@"^2.6.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     vuetify@"^2.6" from @nuxtjs/vuetify@1.12.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@nuxtjs/vuetify
npm ERR!       dev @nuxtjs/vuetify@"^1.12.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! vuex-persist@"^3.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: vue@3.2.31
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   peer vue@"^3.0.2" from vuex@4.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/vuex
npm ERR!     peer vuex@">=2.5" from vuex-persist@3.1.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/vuex-persist
npm ERR!       vuex-persist@"^3.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/me/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2022-02-28T11_06_47_549Z-debug-0.log
```

This issue can be reproducted this way:

```
npm init nuxt-app foo
cd foo
npm install --save vuex-persist
npm up
```

Answer (score 3):

I finally fixed it by setting `"vuex": "<4"` in my `package.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    ...,
    "vuex": "<4"
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Fixed my npm ERR! as well. But I don't really like to have to limit the Vuex version. I'd like to find another solution.

Wondering why it's coming up as conflict. Was working perfectly last Friday, don't think I did any update since then and this morning I had almost the same error as you (my first err part is talking about @nuxtjs/auth-next as well and then about tiptap@1.32.2)